# How to read specific value from object in ViewList?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin

I pass a list of objects via code behind to XAML. The output I get is "*X model*" because it's an object. How can I read specific data from that object inside XAML?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding toBinding, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

code behind:

```
public List<MyObject> toBinding{ get; set; }

    public constructor() {
       //..passing a list of "MyObject" into passingObjectList;
       toBinding = passingObjectList;
    }
```

`MyObject` containts:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

How can I read e.g. `Name` and `Id` instead showing `"X model"` in the screen?

Comment: Just noticed you have both WPF and Xamarin as tags, their XAML is not the same so you should mark only the right one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `ListView`'s `ItemTemplate`:

Example to show the name:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding toBinding, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

[See here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/data-templates/creating/) for a full example.

Comment: I get the error:` System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Xamarin.Forms is not the same thing as WPF...Try this if you are developing a Xamarin.Forms app:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding toBinding}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="Id:" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Name:" />

                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Id}" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

The following applies to WPF only.

If you want to display *either* the name or id you could use the DisplayMemberPath property:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding toBinding}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

If you want to display both you should define an ItemTemplate that contains a Panel that can hold at least two TextBlocks (and any other UIElements):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding toBinding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Id:" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Name:" />

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Id}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I get the error: `Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 16:52. Cannot assign property "DisplayMemberPath": Property does not exists, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property` for the first code. And for the second code: `Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 25:12. Type TextBlock not found in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms`. Any idea?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms is the same thing as WPF...please tag your questions correctly. Please also see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do it as follow:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding toBinding, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <ViewCell>
               <Grid>
                   <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
               </Grid>
           </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This should do the work